# MySQL Update Query Not Working For Different Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've came across strange issue. I know I'm missing something very minor. Can Any One solve the problem plz.
This is my table:

```
     cat_id name              desc
        1   Cricket Schedule     
        2   Live Cricket      Live Cricket Desc
        3   Fixtures     
        4   Videos
```

I ran following update query and worked fine.

```
UPDATE cats 
set name='New Fixtures' 
WHERE cat_id='3'
```

But When I Run Following Query, It returns error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc='New Fixtures Desc' WHERE cat_id='3'' at line 1

The Query is :

```
UPDATE cats 
set desc='New Fixtures Desc' 
WHERE cat_id='3'
```

Plz Tell me What I am Missing Here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved keyword, you must escape it with backtick

```
UPDATE cats 
set `desc` = 'New Fixtures Desc' 
WHERE cat_id = '3'
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: UPDATE cats set desc='New Fixtures descriptive Text' WHERE cat_id='3'
this is not working too

Comment: Should I change the name of Column instead ??

Comment: you may if you want (*to prevent headache in the future*) :D but you can still use that provided that you escaped it with backtick, see example above.

Comment: Thank you Every one. Problem Fixed after changing column Name from desc to anything else as desc is reserved word.